# Insert index value from other index value in same array

Tags: javascript, arrays

For eg.

```
let arr = [];
arr[content] = [];
arr[media]=["abc"];
arr[hey]=["hello"];
```

kindly add the value in arr[content] from arr[media].
I have simply tried a[content]=a[media] but it's not working.

Here, content,media,hey is index of array like arr[1],arr[2],arr[3]. Don't mix with object.

Comment: `let obj = {};`

Comment: Is `arr` supposed to be an index based array (`0:"",1:"",2""`) or an associative array (`"hey": "", "content": "", "media": ""`)?

Comment: JavaScript does not support associative arrays. You should use objects when you want the element names to be strings (text).

Comment: Are `content`, `media` and `hey` variables with an integer values, or are they the index of the values? `var content = 0; arr[content] = [];` or `arr["content"] = [];`

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear in your question if `content`, `media` and `hey` are variables with integer values or if they are the keys of the array. So I will give you an answer for both cases.

### Case 1: Variables

If this is the case then your code should look something like this:

```
let content = 1;
let media = 2;
let hey = 3;

let arr = [];

arr[content] = [];
arr[media]=["abc"];
arr[hey]=["hello"];
```

In this case all you have to do to set the value of the `content` to the value of the `media` is `arr[content] = arr[media]`. Now the value of `content` will be an array with the string `abc`.

```js
let content = 1;
let media = 2;
let hey = 3;

let arr = [];

arr[content] = [];
arr[media] = ["abc"];
arr[hey] = ["hello"];

arr[content] = arr[media];

console.log(arr[content]);
```

### Case 2: Keys

In JavaScript the index of an array can only be a positive integer. The reason why your code doesn't throw an error is because arrays are an extension of objects.

So the following code

```
let arr = [];
arr["content"] = [];
arr["media"]=["abc"];
arr["hey"]=["hello"];
```

Is identical to

```
let arr = {};
arr["content"] = [];
arr["media"]=["abc"];
arr["hey"]=["hello"];
```

In this case all you have to do to set the value of the `content` to the value of the `media` is `arr["content"] = arr["media"]`. Now the value of `content` will be an array with the string `abc`.

```js
let arr = {};

arr["content"] = [];
arr["media"] = ["abc"];
arr["hey"] = ["hello"];

arr["content"] = arr["media"];

console.log(arr["content"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Javascript are list of values with numerical indexes. What you are expressing here is actually objects, in this case with properties. I would rewrite this code like this:

```js
/*let arr = [];
arr[content] = [];
arr[media]=["abc"];
arr[hey]=["hello"]; */

let obj = {};
obj.content = [];
obj.media=["abc"];
obj.hey=["hello"];

// *ADDING THE CONTENT OF obj.media TO obj.content

obj.media.forEach(element => obj.content.push(element));

// AND HERE'S A TEST

alert(obj.content);
```

Answer (score -2):

@Raghav Sehgal , JavaScript does not support associative arrays. You should use objects when you want the element names to be strings (text).

Answer (score -3):

```js
let arr = [];
arr['content'] = [];
arr['media'] = ["abc"];
arr['hey'] = ["hello"];

arr['content'] = arr['media']

console.log(arr['content'])
```

Comment: may I know the reason of downvote as I am not aware of many things how stackoverflow works?

Comment: Code only answers are often frowned upon. Provide an explanation as to why you code works, or what it is supposed to do.